# (Quick and simple) what is this code doing, exactly?

Tags: php, if-statement

```
if ($_POST['foo']) {
    // bar
}
```

Is this saying `...if the $_POST['foo'] variable is a boolean, and is true...`,

Or is this saying `... if the $_POST['foo'] variable isset...`,

Or is this saying `... if the $_POST['foo'] variable is not null...`,

Or is this saying a combination of those things? Or is this saying something completely different?

Comment: boolean comparison: http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's checking the trueness of that value. If it's 0, empty, or the key doesn't exist then it's false. If the key doesn't exist then it will also emit a notice.

Answer (score 1):

It verifies the boolean value of the variable you are passing. It will be true if the variable equals the boolean true, if it contains something that isn't empty (for example, an array) or any value that isn't null (a number that isn't zero).

Here are a few examples, from the PHP documentation (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) :

```
var_dump((bool) "");        // bool(false)
var_dump((bool) 1);         // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) -2);        // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) "foo");     // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) 2.3e5);     // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) array(12)); // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) array());   // bool(false)
var_dump((bool) "false");   // bool(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general anything that goes into conditional statement has to be wither a boolean or it has to evaluate to boolean.

That will also be the case with `$_POST['foo']` it will check if the value of the variable is boolean or if it evaluates to boolean. Any string and number that does not equal to `""` and `0` respectively will be treated as `true` where as `""` and `0` (or is empty) will be treated as `false`. If the variable is undefined you will get a `Undefined variable` notice and the statement will also evaluate to `false`